# Run length encoding in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a simple Python algorithm to solve this problem. Can you please help me figure out how to do this?

> If any character is repeated more than 4 times, the entire set of
> repeated characters should be replaced with a slash '/', followed by a
> 2-digit number which is the length of this run of repeated characters,
> and the character. For example, "aaaaa" would be encoded as "/05a".
> Runs of 4 or less characters should not be replaced since performing
> the encoding would not decrease the length of the string.

Comment: Aside: You may want to look at `collections.Counter` and `itertools.groupby`. Both are very effective ways to count repeats in sequences.

Comment: What should happen if it repeats more than 99 times?

Comment: By the way, this code will fail if the input is something like `/05c` because it has no concept of escaping input correctly. You either need to handle `/` especially, or compress *every* occurrence, not just runs of length > 4.

Answer (score 11):

I see many great solutions here but none that feels very pythonic to my eyes. So I'm contributing with a implementation I wrote myself today for this problem.

```
from typing import Iterator, Tuple
from itertools import groupby

def run_length_encode(data: str) -> Iterator[Tuple[str, int]]:
    """Returns run length encoded Tuples for string"""
    # A memory efficient (lazy) and pythonic solution using generators
    return ((x, sum(1 for _ in y)) for x, y in groupby(data))
```

This will return a generator of Tuples with the character and number of instances, but can easily be modified to return a string as well. A benefit of doing it this way is that it's all lazy evaluated and won't consume more memory or cpu than needed if you don't need to exhaust the entire search space.

If you still want string encoding the code can quite easily be modified for that use case like this:

```
def run_length_encode(data: str) -> str:
    """Returns run length encoded string for data"""
    # A memory efficient (lazy) and pythonic solution using generators
    return "".join(f"{x}{sum(1 for _ in y)}" for x, y in groupby(data))
```

This is a more generic run length encoding for all lengths, and not just for those of over 4 characters. But this could also quite easily be adapted with a conditional for the string if wanted.

Answer (score 7):

Rosetta Code has [a lot of implementations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), that should easily be adaptable to your usecase.

Here is Python code with regular expressions:

```
from re import sub

def encode(text):
    '''
    Doctest:
        >>> encode('WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW')
        '12W1B12W3B24W1B14W'    
    '''
    return sub(r'(.)\1*', lambda m: str(len(m.group(0))) + m.group(1),
               text)

def decode(text):
    '''
    Doctest:
        >>> decode('12W1B12W3B24W1B14W')
        'WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW'
    '''
    return sub(r'(\d+)(\D)', lambda m: m.group(2) * int(m.group(1)),
               text)

textin = "WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"
assert decode(encode(textin)) == textin
```

Comment: `(.)\1*` matches a character and then 0 or more of the same. That is, it matches all the runs, so the substitute function can encode them.  For decoding `(\d+)(\D)` matches a number and something not a number. E.g. 12w.

Answer (score 5):

Aside for setting `a=i` after encoding a sequence and setting a width for your int when printed into the string. You could also do the following which takes advantage of pythons [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Its also a good idea to use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) when constructing strings.

```
from itertools import groupby

def runLengthEncode (plainText):
    res = []

    for k,i in groupby(plainText):
        run = list(i)
        if(len(run) > 4):
            res.append("/{:02}{}".format(len(run), k))
        else:
            res.extend(run)

    return "".join(res)
```

Comment: +1, but if the plainText is long you're adding up a string over and over, which is costly because strings are immutable. You could nest a generator to make it faster and still very easy to read. But since I can't put formatted code in a comment, here's a one-liner: `''.join('/{:02}{}'.format(n,c) if n>4 else c*n for c,n in [(c,len(list(g))) for c,g in groupby(t)])`

Comment: @kojiro Good idea, you are right. I implemented what you suggested in multiline format.

Answer (score 2):

Just observe the behaviour:

```
>>> runLengthEncode("abcd")
'abc'
```

Last character is ignored. You have to append what you've collected.

```
>>> runLengthEncode("abbbbbcd")
'a/5b/5b'
```

Oops, problem after encoding. You should set `a=i` even if you found a long enough sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the most efficient solution, but we haven't studied functions like `groupby()` yet so here's what I did:

```
def runLengthEncode (plainText):
    res=''
    a=''
    count = 0
    for i in plainText:
        count+=1
        if a.count(i)>0:
            a+=i
        else:
            if len(a)>4:
                if len(a)<10:
                    res+="/0"+str(len(a))+a[0][:1]
                else:
                    res+="/" + str(len(a)) + a[0][:1]
                a=i
            else:
                res+=a
                a=i
        if count == len(plainText):
            if len(a)>4:
                if len(a)<10:
                    res+="/0"+str(len(a))+a[0][:1]
                else:
                    res+="/" + str(len(a)) + a[0][:1]
            else:
                res+=a
    return(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Split=(list(input("Enter string: ")))
Split.append("")
a = 0
for i in range(len(Split)):
    try:
        if (Split[i] in Split) >0:
            a = a + 1
        if Split[i] != Split[i+1]:
            print(Split[i],a)
            a = 0
    except IndexError:
        print()
```

this is much easier and works everytime

Answer (score 0):

```
def RLE_comp_encode(text):
    if text == text[0]*len(text) :
        return str(len(text))+text[0]
    else:
        comp_text , r = '' , 1
        for i in range (1,len(text)):
            if text[i]==text[i-1]:
                r +=1
                if i == len(text)-1:
                    comp_text += str(r)+text[i]
            else :
                comp_text += str(r)+text[i-1]
                r = 1
    return comp_text
```

This worked for me,

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [groupby()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function combined with a list/generator comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby, imap

''.join(x if reps <= 4 else "/%02d%s" % (reps, x) for x, reps in imap(lambda x: (x[0], len(list(x[1]))), groupby(s)))
```

Comment: `>>> import this`

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution to run-length encoding which I can think of:

For encoding a string like `"a4b5c6d7..."`:

```
def encode(s):
    counts = {}
    for c in s:
        if counts.get(c) is None:
            counts[c] = s.count(c)
    return "".join(k+str(v) for k,v in counts.items())
```

For decoding a string like `"aaaaaabbbdddddccccc...."`:

```
def decode(s):
    return "".join((map(lambda tup:  tup[0] * int(tup[1]), zip(s[0:len(s):2], s[1:len(s):2]))))
```

Fairly easy to read and simple.

Comment: Dictionaries do not guarantee sort order

Answer (score -1):

```
text=input("Please enter the string to encode")
encoded=[]
index=0
amount=1
while index<=(len(text)-1):  
  if index==(len(text)-1) or text[index]!=text[(index+1)]:
    encoded.append((text[index],amount))        
    amount=1
  else:
    amount=amount+1            
  index=index+1   
print(encoded)
```