# Run Length Encoding in Python with List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I have a more basic Run Length Encoding question compared to many of the questions about this topic that have already been answered. Essentially, I'm trying to take the string

```
string = 'aabccccaaa'
```

and have it return

```
a2b1c4a3
```

I thought that if I can manage to get all the information into a list like I have illustrated below, I would easily be able to return a2b1c4a3

```
test = [['a','a'], ['b'], ['c','c','c','c'], ['a','a','a']]
```

I came up with the following code so far, but was wondering if someone would be able to help me figure out how to make it create the output I illustrated above.

```
def string_compression():
    for i in xrange(len(string)):
        prev_item, current_item = string[i-1], string[i]
        print prev_item, current_item
        if prev_item == current_item:
            <HELP>
```

If anyone has any additional comments regarding more efficient ways to go about solving a question like this I am all ears!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run length encoding in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948382/run-length-encoding-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

grouped = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(string)]
```

This will produce your per-letter groups as a list of lists.

You can turn that into a RLE in one step:

```
rle = ''.join(['{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(string)])
```

Each `k` is the letter being grouped, each `g` an iterator producing N times the same letter; the `sum(1 for _ in g)` expression counts those in the most efficient way possible.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> string = 'aabccccaaa'
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(string)]
[['a', 'a'], ['b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
>>> ''.join(['{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(string)])
'a2b1c4a3'
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! I understand that how the code [list(g) for k, g in groupby(string)] works, but I'm getting caught on the first part. What you're doing is saying I've got a string of length 0 and to that string I want to join the sum of the smaller lists within the larger lists. Where I'm lost is at the piece join(['{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) and I was wondering if you could explain in a little greater detail how that works?

Comment: @ADT: the empty string is the joiner, what is placed between the elements of the list produced. Try out `' - '.join(']['foo', 'bar', 'spam'])` for example and vary that joiner. Also try out what *just* the `['{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(string)]` list comprehension produces.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [`more_itertools.run_length`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.run_length) tool.

**Demo**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = "aabccccaaa"
list(mit.run_length.encode(iterable))
# [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 4), ('a', 3)]
```

**Code**

```
"".join(f"{x[0]}{x[1]}" for x in mit.run_length.encode(iterable))  # python 3.6
# 'a2b1c4a3'
```

```
"".join(x[0] + str(x[1]) for x in mit.run_length.encode(iterable))
# 'a2b1c4a3'
```

Alternative itertools/functional style:

```
"".join(map(str, it.chain.from_iterable(x for x in mit.run_length.encode(iterable))))
# 'a2b1c4a3'
```

*Note: `more_itertools` is a third-party library that installable via [`pip install more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools).*

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Python beginner and this is what I wrote for RLE.

```
s = 'aabccccaaa'
grouped_d = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(s)]

result = ''
for key, count in grouped_d:
    result += key + str(count)

print(f'result = {result}')
```