# Python, simple compression/encoding algorithm

Tags: python

I have a string which contains only 0 and 1. I need to encode it in a form of ranges of 1's.

Example input:

```
01101110
```

Example output:

```
[[1,2], [4,6]]
```

Update: Need to produce [begin,end] array of 1's sequence indexes. 
As per example:
First sequence of 1's starts at index 1 and finishes at index 2.
Second sequence starts at index 4 and finishes at index 6

Minimum length of sequence is 1. So `"1"` input produces `[[0,0]]` output

How should I do it?

Comment: sounds like you're looking for Run Length Encoding see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537028/run-length-encoding-in-python-with-list-comprehension

Comment: @das-g, yet it does. Original question is updated

Comment: @das-g It is the ranges.

Comment: @IrmendeJong Thanks for a help attempt! But its not exactly what Im looking for, see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

string = '01101110'

start = 0
out = []
for k,g in groupby(string):
    delta = len(list(g))    
    if k == '1':
        out.append([start,start+delta-1])
    start += delta

print(out)
```

Returns:

```
[[1, 2], [4, 6]]
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much