# Python Consecutive characters

Tags: python-3.x

If a string is given, substitute the character with number of times that character is repeated only if the character is repeated more than three times consecutively like below

> Input: aaaaa   Output: 5Za
>
> Input:  addeeeeuyyyyy  OutPut: add4Zeu5Zy

Tried like below:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> strs="aaaaa"
>>> [[k, len(list(g))] for k, g in groupby(strs)]
[['a', 5]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a good part of it - you need to implement the restriction of only abbreviating consecutive letters that occure 4+ times and add the `'Z'` to the output.

You could do it like so:

```
from itertools import groupby


def run_length_encode(data):
    result = []
    for letter,amount in ( (k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(data)):
        result.append(letter*amount if amount < 4 else f'{amount}Z{letter}')

    return ''.join(result)

data = "someaaaaabbbcdccdd"  
print(data, run_length_encode(data), sep = "=>" )
```

Output:

```
someaaaaabbbcdccdd => some5Zabbbcdccdd
```

You can find more solutions (regex f.e.) in this related post:

- [Run length encoding in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948382/run-length-encoding-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Along the same thought process you were using.

```
from itertools import groupby

def condense(strs):
    new_str = ''

    for k, g in groupby(strs):
        length = len(list(g))
        if length > 3:
            new_str += f'{length}Z{k}'
        else:
            new_str += k*length
    return new_str

print(condense('aaaaa '))
print(condense('addeeeeuyyyyy'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=input()
ini=""
ans=""
for i in range(len(s)):
    if ini=="":
        ini=s[i]
        c=0
    if ini==s[i]:
        c=c+1
    if ini!=s[i]:
        if c>=3:
            ans=ans+str(c)+"Z"+ini
        else:
            ans=ans+c*ini
        ini=s[i]
        c=1
if c!=0 and c<3:
    ans=ans+c*ini
elif c!=0 and c>=3:
    ans=ans+str(c)+"Z"+ini
print(ans)
```