# How to pull elements from a list that are nested between particular elements, and add them to new lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a daypart column (str), which has 1s or 0s for each hour of the day, depending if we choose to run a campaign during that hour.

Example:

```
daypart = '110011100111111100011110'
```

I want to convert this to the following string format:

`'0-1, 4-6, 9-15, 19-22'`

The above format is more readable, and shows during which hours the campaign ran.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
hours_list = []

ind = 0
for x in daypart:
    if int(x) == 1:
        hours_list.append(ind)
    else:
        hours_list.append('exclude')
    ind += 1
```

The above gives me a list like this:

```
[0, 1, 'exclude', 'exclude', 4, 5, 6, 'exclude', 'exclude', 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 19, 20, 21, 22, 'exclude']
```

Now I want to find a way to make the above into my desired output. What I am thinking of doing is finding which elements exist between 'exclude', and start adding them to new lists. I can then take the smallest and largest element from each list, join them with a '-', and append all such lists together.

Any ideas how I can do this, or a simpler way to do all of this?

Comment: Why not convert to your desired format directly without the intermediate representation?

Comment: Also, I suggest you check out the `enumerate()` function.

Comment: Very similar: [Run length encoding in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948382/run-length-encoding-in-python)

Comment: I don't understand how to convert directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's simple, readable code to get all intervals:

```
daypart = '1111111111111111111111'
hours= []
start, end = -1, -1
for i in range(len(daypart)):
    if daypart[i] == "1":
        if end != -1:
            end += 1 
        else:
            start = i 
            end = i 
    else:
        if end!=-1:
            hours.append([start, end])
            start, end = -1,-1
if end!=-1:
    hours.append([start, end])
    start, end = -1,-1

print(hours)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you convert directly to your desired format rather than using an intermediate representation that has the exact same information as the original input. Let's think about how we can do this in words:

1. Look for the first `1` in the input string
2. Add the index to a list
3. Look for the next `0` in the string.
4. Append one less than found index to a list. (Or maybe append the index from steps 2 and 4 as a pair?)
5. Continue by looking for the next `1` and repeat steps 2-4.

I leave translating this into code as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: After Step 4, how do I add the next index to a new list? That's where I'm stuck : (

Comment: This put me in the right direction though. Thank You very much : )

Comment: @HamzaKhalid Add the next index to the same list, not a new one.

Comment: @HamzaKhalid Note that the key here is to first explain the steps **in words** to solve the problem you are working on. It is much easier for us to think in our native human languages when solving a new problem. This first draft might not actually be clear enough to translate directly into code, but it is a starting point that we can refine in more and more detail **in English**. When the English is clear enough, then we can translate into Python.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thank You :D

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `itertools.groupby`, `operator.itemgetter`, `enumerate` in a comprehension to achieve this as well:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
daypart = '110011100111111100011110'
get_ends, get_one = itemgetter(0,-1), itemgetter(1)

output = ', '.join('{0[0]}-{1[0]}'.format(*get_ends(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(enumerate(daypart), get_one) if k=='1')
print(output)
```

---

```
0-1, 4-6, 9-15, 19-22
```

`get_ends` gets the first and last elements in each group and `get_one` just gets element `1` so to use it as a key.