# Converting string in python by counting letters next to eachother

Tags: python, string

I tried many ways but neither worked. I have to convert string like `assdggg` to `a2sd3g` in python. If letters are next to each other we leave only one letter and before it we write how mamy of them were next to eachother. Any idea how can it be done?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is a form of string compression. This article may help: https://www.pythonpool.com/string-compression-python/

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [Run length encoding in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948382/run-length-encoding-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest `itertools.groupby` then format as you need

```
from itertools import groupby

# groupby("assdggg")
# {'a': ['a'], 's': ['s', 's'], 'd': ['d'], 'g': ['g', 'g', 'g']}

result = ""
for k, v in groupby("assdggg"):
    count = len(list(v))
    result += (str(count) if count > 1 else "") + k

print(result)  # a2sd3g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

txt = "assdggg"

print(''.join(str(l) + k if (l := len(list(g))) != 1 else k for k, g in groupby(txt)))
```

output :

```
a2sd3g
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
string = 'assdggg'
compression = ''

for char in string :
    if char not in compression :
        if string.count(char) != 1 :
            compression += str(string.count(char))
        compression += char

print(compression)
#'a2sd3g'
```