# Encode the DNA string in such a way that similar subsequent characters are grouped into number of occurrences along with the char

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need help in writing the Python code which would return the following output_string as mentioned below in the examples.

Example 1:

```
input_string = "AAABCCCCDDA"
output_string = "3AB4C2DA"
```

Example 2:

```
input_string = "ABBBBCCDDDDAAAAA"
output_string = "A4B2C4D5A"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run length encoding in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948382/run-length-encoding-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

In python 3.8+, You can use [`walrus`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) operator `(:=)` and write a short approach.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> input_string = "ABBBBCCDDDDAAAAA"
>>> ''.join(f"{len_g}{k}" if (len_g := len(list(g))) > 1 else k for k, g in groupby(input_string))
'A4B2C4D5A'
```

In Python < 3.8:

```
from itertools import groupby

input_string = "AAABCCCCDDA"

st = ''
for k, g in groupby(input_string):
    len_g = len(list(g))
    if len_g>1:
        st += f"{len_g}{k}"
    else:
        st += k
         
print(st)
```

Output:`'3AB4C2DA'`

Answer (score 0):

it seems like regex also can do the trick:

```
from re import sub

dna = "AAABCCCCDDA"
sub(r'(\w)\1+',lambda m: str(len(m[0]))+m[1],dna)  # '3AB4C2DA'
```