# Convert list of similar ints to tuple of int and occurances

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of integers as following

`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, -64, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1]`

How would I go about converting them into:

`[(1, 10), (7, 12), (-64, 1), (9, 9), (1, 3)]`

Or, in words, a tuple of (the integer, the amount of integers in a row)

I have tried the following

```
diff = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, -64, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1]

found = 0
new = []
for i,j in zip(diff, diff[1:]):
    if i == j:
        found += 1
    else:
        new.append((i, found))
        found = 0
```

But it doesn't look great and doesn't work either, returns
`[(1, 17), (7, 11), (-64, 0)]`

Comment: No, this one is the correct duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948382/run-length-encoding-in-python

Comment: `from itertools import groupby;[(char, len(list(group))) for char, group in groupby(diff)]`