# How to represent IPv6 addresses in bitshift notation efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have a database of IPv6 networks, and I want to represent the IPv6 addresses using bit-shift notation when displaying as integers. Because IPv6 addresses have a maximum of 2<sup>128</sup>-1, the numbers when displayed in decimal have so many digits, they are so stupidly large I cannot comprehend them easily.

This is an example IPv6 address in decimal form: 334965454937798799971759379190646833152, and this is the only time I will ever include IPv6 address in decimal form in this post.

When displayed in hexadecimal form there is a lot of repetition, the strings are longer than they need to be, and it would make sense to use bit-shift notation to reduce duplication therefore increase information density and make the string more compact.

For example, the following are all the reserved IPv6 networks according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses), and I have merged the overlapping ranges:

```
data = [
    (0x0, 0x1),
    (0xffff00000000, 0xffffffffffff),
    (0xffff000000000000, 0xffff0000ffffffff),
    (0x64ff9b000000000000000000000000, 0x64ff9b0000000000000000ffffffff),
    (0x64ff9b000100000000000000000000, 0x64ff9b0001ffffffffffffffffffff),
    (0x1000000000000000000000000000000, 0x100000000000000ffffffffffffffff),
    (0x20010000000000000000000000000000, 0x20010000ffffffffffffffffffffffff),
    (0x20010020000000000000000000000000, 0x2001002fffffffffffffffffffffffff),
    (0x20010db8000000000000000000000000, 0x20010db8ffffffffffffffffffffffff),
    (0x20020000000000000000000000000000, 0x2002ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff),
    (0xfc000000000000000000000000000000, 0xfdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff),
    (0xfe800000000000000000000000000000, 0xfebfffffffffffffffffffffffffffff),
    (0xff000000000000000000000000000000, 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
]
```

As you can see, there are lots of consecutive zeros and fs, when there are lots of zeros, the number is equal to the value on the left times 2 to the power of length of zeros times 4, so can can represent it by left shift the value on the left length of zeros times 4 bits. And when there are lots of fs, the number is the value on the left plus one times a power of 2 minus one...

I want to reduce the duplication so that the maximum number of consecutive ones and zeros in hexadecimal is 4, in binary that is 16.

Let me show you what I mean:

```
def bitshift_repr(n):
    if not n:
        return '0'
    binary = f'{n:b}'
    zeros = 0
    ones = 0
    if binary.endswith('0') and (l := len(binary)) - (i := binary.rindex('1')) > 16:
        zeros = l - i - 1
        binary = binary[:i+1]
    if '0' in binary and (l := len(binary)) - (i := binary.rindex('0')) > 16:
        ones = l - i - 1
        binary = f'{binary[:i]}1'
    if binary == '1' * (l := len(binary)) and l > 16:
        s = f'(1<<{hex(l)})-1'
        return f'{s}<<{zeros}' if zeros else s
    s = hex(int(binary, 2))
    if ones:
        s = f'({s}<<{hex(ones)})-1'
    return f'{s}<<{zeros}' if zeros else s
```

The above function, when fed my example data, would produce the following output:

```
In [213]: for a, b in data:
     ...:     print(f'({bitshift_repr(a)}, {bitshift_repr(b)}),')
(0, 0x1),
(0xffff<<32, (1<<0x30)-1),
(0xffff<<48, (0xffff0001<<0x20)-1),
(0x64ff9b<<96, (0x64ff9b0000000000000001<<0x20)-1),
(0x64ff9b0001<<80, (0x327fcd8001<<0x51)-1),
(0x1<<120, (0x100000000000001<<0x40)-1),
(0x2001<<112, (0x20010001<<0x60)-1),
(0x1000801<<101, (0x2001003<<0x64)-1),
(0x40021b7<<99, (0x20010db9<<0x60)-1),
(0x1001<<113, (0x2003<<0x70)-1),
(0x3f<<122, (0x7f<<0x79)-1),
(0x1fd<<119, (0x3fb<<0x76)-1),
(0xff<<120, (1<<0x80)-1),

In [214]: for a, b in data:
     ...:     assert eval(bitshift_repr(a)) == a and eval(bitshift_repr(b)) == b
```

But the output isn't optimal, as you can see, there are still consecutive runs of zeros (and possibly ones) with length more than 4, `(0x64ff9b0000000000000001<<0x20)-1` should be `(((0x64ff9b<<0x40)+1)<<0x20)-1` and `(0x100000000000001<<0x40)-1` should be `(((1<<56)+1)<<0x40)-1`. In cases like this I want to add the smaller number to the large power of 2.

How can I make the function operate only in integer domain, use bit-shifts in calculations, and make it recursively calling itself to strictly enforce the rule so that there are no more than four consecutive ones or zeros, and make it more efficient in general?

---

I have updated my code, and it produces expected output for my example. I was going to delete this question and post my code on Code Review...

```
import random

def binary_groupby(n):
    return [(d, sum(1 for _ in i)) for d, i in groupby(f'{n:b}')]

def flatten_binary_groups(groups):
    return hex(int(''.join(d * l for d, l in groups), 2)) if groups else 0

def compress_logic(groups, i, l, one):
    before = compress_binary(groups[:i])
    after = flatten_binary_groups(groups[i+1:])
    if one:
        if before:
            if '<<' in before:
                before = f'({before})'
            s = f'({before}+1<<0x{l:x})-1'
        else:
            s = f'(1<<0x{l:x})-1'
    else:
        s = f'{before}<<0x{l:x}' if before else '0'
    if after:
        s = f'({s})+{after}' if s != '0' else after
    return s

def compress_binary(groups):
    if not (l := len(groups)):
        return ''
    i = l - 1
    compressed = False
    one = False
    while i >= 0:
        d, l = groups[i]
        if l > 16:
            compressed = True
            if d == '1':
                one = True
        if compressed:
            return compress_logic(groups, i, l, one)
        i -= 1
    return flatten_binary_groups(groups)

def bit_shift_repr(n):
    return compress_binary(binary_groupby(n))


for a, b in data:
    print(f'({bit_shift_repr(a)}, {bit_shift_repr(b)}),')
    assert eval(bit_shift_repr(a)) == a and eval(bit_shift_repr(b)) == b
```

---

### ***But I have found out it doesn't work properly***

```
def generate_ipv6():
    n = random.randrange(2**24)
    l = n.bit_length()
    while l < 128:
        if bits := min(random.randrange(18, 32), 128 - l):
            n <<= bits
            l += bits
            if random.randrange(2):
                n -= 1
    return n

for _ in range(256):
    n = generate_ipv6()
    print(hex(n))
    s = bit_shift_repr(n)
    print(s)
    assert eval(s) == n
```

```
In [390]: for _ in range(256):
     ...:     n = generate_ipv6()
     ...:     print(hex(n))
     ...:     s = bit_shift_repr(n)
     ...:     print(s)
     ...:     assert eval(s) == n
0xbc3c7ffffff7ffffffbfffeffffbffff
(((((((((((((0x17878+1<<0x1b)-1)+0x0)+1<<0x1c)-1)+0x0)+1<<0x11)-1)+0x0)+1<<0x11)-1)+0x0)+1<<0x12)-1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[390], line 6
      4 s = bit_shift_repr(n)
      5 print(s)
----> 6 assert eval(s) == n

AssertionError:
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Sounds like you could use [Run Length Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948382/run-length-encoding-in-python) to solve this.